# Is it bad practice to keep everything in one table?

Tags: mysqli, indexing

Looking for some feedback - I am building a  social networking type software-  one of the features allows users to post news stories and have friends comment. I have in the past kept different tables for things like news, comments, calendar events, etc. However a friend has turned me to the wordpress-type database structure of "POSTS" and "post_types" where everything is in one table and has a "post_type".

This would mean that news stories, comments, events, etc are all in the same table. I love the efficiency of creating functions that are updating one table. HOWEVER, a single table in my old software was 1.5MILLION rows, I'd expect this new table to grow to about 10Million in the first year.

Does mysql handle this size of data okay as long as indexes are properly set, or is it smarter to break everything into seperate tables for this reason?

Answer (score 0):

There is no general answer. It depends.

MySQL has no problem dealing with large tables. However, it will not do miracles for you. In the end, it's all about efficiency. It means you need to optimize your design for multiple, mutually exclusive goals. What you want to find is a sweet spot between complexity, performance, extensibility and maintenance costs. This is different for every project and is kind of an art.

Generally don't want to mix things that are too different. This is why they teach about data normalization in just about every database book or CS course. If your data is small, this does not really matter. But if you have a lot of data and a lot of requests, you will almost certainly want to squeeze every last drop of performance from your database. So not only will you be separating tables, scrutinizing indexes, inspecting execution plans, updating statistics, defragmenting pages and measuring performance, but you will also be using partitioning, clustering, materialized views, read-only replicas, I/O and CPU parallelism, SSDs, Memcached and a variety of other tools. This will all be much more challenging if you have started with a bad data model. In my personal experience, locking is something that really bites you in the ass with large tables, unless you can somehow live without transactions.

To make any kinds of estimations, you need to have some performance baseline. Just knowing number of records is not enough. How many requests will there be? What will the queries be doing? Where do you expect the heaviest load? Can you prepare the most common queries that the system will be running most of the time? What about peak hours? What hardware will be available to run this load? What is the ratio of reads to writes? Etc.

To make optimizations, you need some kind of goal. As always, you will find out that in order to get there, you have to sacrifice something. Because you probably don't have all those answers yet, try following the principle of minimalism - start small, measure, analyze, improve, repeat.